# Prevent Component from Unmouting when Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-router-v4

I have a child component that I need to keep when routing away from the parent component.
search the web and most answers where about "react-router", but I am using "react-router-dom" (aka React Router V4).
Im fairly new to react and thought this should be fairly simple like flagging the component to not be unmounted or something like this.

```
import Home from "./home/Home";
import Top from "./top/Top";

export default class Layout extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <div class="wrp">
                    <Menu/>
                    <section class="left">
                        <Header/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                            <Route exact path="/top" component={Top} />
                        </Switch>
                        <Footer/>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Inside the "Home" component there is a child component that needs to stay in the DOM.

**As Requested** The Home and child component code:

```
import React from "react";

import Sponsor from "./Sponsor";
import Feature from "./Feature";
import Top from "./Top";
import Discord from "./Discord";
import Middle from "./Middle";

export default class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <section class="main_wrp">
                <Sponsor/>
                <div class="bulk">
                    <Feature/>
                    <div class="co6">
                        <Top/>
                        <Discord/>
                    </div>
                    <Middle/>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Child Component (Discord):

```
import React from "react";

export default class Discord extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(

            <div class="DiscordViewer">
                <embed height='500px'src='https://somelink.com' />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to navigate away from Home but still show the child of Home, I think the child would need to be outside Home component. Can you post the code for the Home component and Child component?

Comment: @palsrealm added the requested code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying the component tree, preserving your leaf node component (Discord in this example) after navigating away from its parent node would violate the definition of a tree. You couldn't simply hide and reposition the component using CSS, you would have to do so for the entire branch of the tree, from the nearest parent, that led to that leaf node. This would likely result in unwanted complexity and poor performance, though it could be performed like so:

```
const HomeWrapper = withRouter(props => (
  <div style={props.location.pathname !== '/' ? {display: 'none'} : {}}>
    <Home {...props} />
  <div>
))

<HomeWrapper />
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/top" component={Top} />
  <Route exact path="/other" component={OtherComponent} />
</Switch>
```

If you're flexible in your component structure, you can move your Discord component out of the home route into a hidden div. You'll then use non-react DOM manipulation to move discord between an external hidden div and a shown div within Home. In your Home component, you can render DiscordWrapper component shown below. You'll want to return false from shouldComponentUpdate to block updates. :

```
<div id='discord-wrapper-external' style={{display: 'none'}}>
  <Discord id='discord-dom-node'/>
</div>

class DiscordWrapper extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.el = document.getElementById('discord-dom-node')
    document.getElementById('discord-wrapper-internal').appendChild(this.el)
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.getElementById('discord-wrapper-external').appendChild(this.el)
  }
  render() {
    return <div id='discord-wrapper-internal' />
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing it is to take the `<Discord\>` component out of Home.
So in Layout, you create the `<Discord\>` component and pass it as a child to all the other components.

Layout

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let discord = <Discord/>;
        return(
            <Router>
                <div class="wrp">
                    <Menu/>
                    <section class="left">
                        <Header/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" render={()=><Home>{discord}</Home>} />
                            <Route exact path="/top" render={()=><Top>{discord}</Top>} />
                        </Switch>
                        <Footer/>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

And your Home component would become

```
export default class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <section class="main_wrp">
                <Sponsor/>
                <div class="bulk">
                    <Feature/>
                    <div class="co6">
                        <Top/>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                    <Middle/>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

You can also pass the `<Discord/>` component as a named prop to all the components that need to show it, instead of passing it as a child component.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this won't help because what I am trying to avoid is to load the Discord component everytime I am returning to home.
The Discord component is a really heavy embed that should be loaded once.
So my plan was to just style it away when the client isn't in the home page. (position absoulute, opacity 0)